# NumericUpDown control ignores AutoScaleMode for Margin

Tags: .net, winforms, hdpi

Simple case: Create a `Form` in the Visual Studio designer and sets its `AutoScaleMode` value to `Dpi`. Then place a `NumericUpDown` control and a `TextBox` in two rows of a `TableLayoutPanel`. Now set both controls' `Margin` property to 10 pixels. Also provide an according manifest file to enable High DPI support for the process.

If the program runs in a different DPI scaling than it was designed in, the `NumericUpDown` margin of the input control is different. All other controls can scale their margin properly, just not this one.

Hint: Running with debugger (F5) always runs at 96 dpi, but running without debugger (Ctrl+F5) uses the native system DPI setting. That's how you can test both.

Is that a bug? Can it be fixed?

Comment: NUD was tweaked in .NET 4.6 to behave better on high dpi monitors.  Be sure to [edit the config file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx) to turn that on.  Whether that also takes care of the margin, hmm, you'll have to try. You can of course very easily fix it yourself with code in the form constructor that uses CreateGraphics + Graphics.DpiY.

Comment: The "EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing" setting doesn't fix it. I'm currently targeting .NET 4.6 and probably running 4.6.1 (VS 2015.2 on Windows 10).

Comment: @HansPassant Forgot to tag you, you're probably not notified for follow-up comments. And please define "NUD".